# What is the reason for these float results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-accuracy

for the code below, why is the first result a small decimal number but the second results in 0? My main question is why that extra decimal place makes the second result a 0. Does python have a limit in its decimal places when calculating floats?

```py
x =5.000000000000001
y =5
print(x-y)
x =5.0000000000000001
y =5
print(x-y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Float is not always precise because of how the data is stored. They need to be rounded to work properly in practice.

```
x =5.000000000000001
y =5
print(round(x-y))
x =5.0000000000000001
y =5
print(x-y)
```

Comment: Rounding floating-point numbers is not a proper way to make them “work.”